# Excel - how to calculate age from 'Age in Months'

Tags: excel, excel-2007

If a person's age in months is 140 how could I calculate there age in Years and Months?

So for example I would want to see:

11 Years 8 Months

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the months: `=MOD(140,12)`

To get the years: `=ROUNDDOWN(140/12,0)`

Putting it together `=ROUNDDOWN($A$1/12,0) & " Years " & MOD($A$1,12) & " Months"` where $A$1 holds the value (140).